# Rotation of the plane of oscillation of the Foucault pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, coriolis-effect

If the plane of oscillation of the Foucault pendulum rotates due to the Coriolis effect, shouldn't the rotation be counterclockwise in the Northern Hemisphere, similar to the rotation of tornadoes? Or is my understanding of the Foucault pendulum wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diagram below gives a schematic representation of formation of cyclonic flow (Northern Hemisphere)

[image]

(This image is also on wikipedia; uploaded by me)

The blue arrows represent direction of pressure gradient, the red arrows represent the direction of tendency to move due to coriolis effect.

Flows from around a low pressure area tend to shepherd each other into a flow pattern *around* the low pressure area.

Notice that for each of the four directions the direction of the red arrows corresponds to the direction in which the pendulum bob is veering as it swings back and forth.

This image is also in use in an earlier answer, to a question titled: [Coriolis effect and weather](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/497221/17198)
The answer there gives a bit more information.