# Movement of the Foucault pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, coriolis-effect

If my understanding of the Foucault pendulum is correct, then if I am in the northern hemisphere and if I let the pendulum oscillate in the north-south direction, then as the bob moves towards the south, it veers off towards **its right** due to the Coriolis effect. But when it returns back towards the north, shouldn't the pendulum veer towards **its right** again due to the Coriolis effect?

Comment: Yes it does - the line of motion keeps rotating.

Comment: Instead of asking "do you mean the 'other' right" I rather just refer you to look at [this animation](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/82/Foucault-rotz.gif)

Comment: Thanks for referring me to the animation. It really helped me understand it.

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/766126/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the Coriolis effect always act with the same orientation relative to:

- referential rotation ( clockwise or counterclockwise),
- oscillation plan.

Within the northern hemisphere, the pendulum will veer toward right from its oscillation plan. Within the southern hemisphere it will veer toward left.

To see it faster just imagine you are running this experiment at the north pole ( or the south one if you prefer ).